# Unable to Initialize ngx-charts with API fetched Data

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, time-series, ngx-charts

I'm having some bad times while trying to initialize a chart built using [ngx-charts](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts) with API fetched data.

I built a rest api that, upon a proper call, spits out some time-series data.

```
{
    "prices": [
        {
            "item": "1",
            "price": 2,
            "estimated": 2.1,
            "date": [
                2012,
                8,
                16
            ]
        },
        {
            "item": "1",
            "price": 3,
            "estimated": 4.1,
            "date": [
                2012,
                9,
                16
            ]
        },
        {
            "item": "1",
            "price": 5,
            "estimated": 7.1,
            "date": [
                2012,
                10,
                16
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I built **price.model.ts** to correctly handle it, and it works just fine

```
export class PriceModel {
    public id: string;
    public price: number;
    public estimated: number;
    public date: number[];

    constructor(
         id: string,
         price: number,
         estimated: number,
         date: number[]
    ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.price = price;
        this.estimated = estimated;
        this.date = date;
     }
}
```

Then, I set up my **details.component.ts** in order to perform such api call, get the data, parse it and render it into the chart.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxChartsModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

/** App Models **/
import { PriceModel } from '../../shared/components/prices/price.model';
import { ChartDataModel } from '../../shared/components/prices/chart-data.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.page.html',
  providers: [NgxChartsModule]
})

export class DetailsPage {

  private sub: any;
  private prices: PriceModel[];
  ngxData: ChartDataModel = {
    data: [
      {
        name: 'prices',
        series: []
      },
      {
        name: 'forecast',
        series: []
      }
    ]
  };

  view: any[] = [1000, 750];

  // options
  showXAxis = true;
  showYAxis = true;
  gradient = false;
  showLegend = true;
  showXAxisLabel = true;
  xAxisLabel = 'Dates';
  showYAxisLabel = true;
  yAxisLabel = 'Prices';

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28', '#C7B42C', '#AAAAAA']
  };

  // line, area
  autoScale = true;

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    console.log(this.ngxData.data);
    Object.assign(this.ngxData);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this._http.get('someroute').subscribe((prices) => {
        this.prices = prices.json().prices;
        let currData;
        this.prices.map((p) => {
          currData = new Date(p.date[0], p.date[1], p.date[2]);
          this.ngxData.data[0].series.push({ name: currData.getTime().toString(), value: p.price });
          this.ngxData.data[1].series.push({ name: currData.getTime().toString(), value: p.estimated });
        });
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Where my **ChartDataModel.ts** is defined as

```
export class ChartDataModel {
    public data: SerieModel[];
    constructor(data:  SerieModel[]) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

export class SerieModel {
    public name: string;
    public series: SeriersChildModel[];
    constructor(name:  string, series: SeriersChildModel[]) {
        this.name = name;
        this.series = series;
    }
}

export class SeriersChildModel {
    public name: string;
    public value: number;
    constructor(name:  string, value: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And, finally, here's my **details.page.html**

```
<ngx-charts-line-chart
  [view]="view"
  [scheme]="colorScheme"
  [results]="ngxData.data"
  [gradient]="gradient"
  [xAxis]="showXAxis"
  [yAxis]="showYAxis"
  [legend]="showLegend"
  [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
  [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
  [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
  [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
  [autoScale]="autoScale">
</ngx-charts-line-chart>
```

Logging `this.ngxData.data` before `Object.assign` prints everything just fine

[image]

But I end up having the following result

[image]

I followed the example available [here](https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-charts/content/charts/line-chart.html) but ended up with no data actually displaying.

I don't understand why, even though data is formatted as the library wants, data isn't shown.

**What Am I doing wrong? Is it caused by a wrong initialization in the constructor?**

Comment: There is quite a lot of code posted here (I'll try to read it anyway), however you may benefit from trying to produce an [mcve]. Or add a [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue) demonstrating the issue, to make it easier to answer.

Comment: Hi @0mpurdy, yes, a Plunk would be really nice but, unluckily, I cannot set up this piece in there since my BE is in local and would be a mess for headers etc.

Comment: Does your details.component.ts render the chart with static data e.g. in a unit test? Just to make sure that ngx-charts is properly imported, set up etc.

Comment: Yes @KimKern, using static data it works just fine.

Comment: You can mock the data coming back in [a plunker like this](https://plnkr.co/edit/4Mrgrot568OsekCQfKtn?p=preview), can you confirm with a `console.log` inside your subscription to check that the API is returning the data correctly?

Comment: I forked it. Yes, the data shown is correct.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your issue is about modifying series by `ngxData.data[x]series.push()` is not recognizing by change detection.

Reassigning `ngxData.data` should be detected : `this.ngxData.data = [...this.ngxData.data]`

```
ngOnInit() {     
    this.sub = this._http.get('someroute').subscribe((prices) => {
        this.prices = prices.json().prices;
        let currData;
        this.prices.map((p) => {
          currData = new Date(p.date[0], p.date[1], p.date[2]);
          this.ngxData.data[0].series.push({ name: currData.getTime().toString(), value: p.price });
          this.ngxData.data[1].series.push({ name: currData.getTime().toString(), value: p.estimated })
        });
        //your solution
        this.ngxData.data = [...this.ngxData.data];
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

I managed to add a plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/JSTcS4FnJ5dshAldLWPL?p=preview

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Its an old question, but still helpfull. Quick Question, what exactly is `var = [...var]` doing? Never seen this.

Comment: @sHamann this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

For my USE CASE ....

first you need to initialize two arrays

Then you need to call your service and for every iteration, we will add object to `saleData` array

```
customers: Customer[] = [];
  saleData: any = [];
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.customerService.getTop10Customers().subscribe(data => {
          this.customers = data._embedded.customers
          console.log(this.customers)
          let sales:any = [];
           this.customers.forEach(c =>{
             sales.push({name: c.designation,value: c.totalMoneySpent})
           })
          // clone the sales array to saleData 
          this.saleData = [...sales]
          console.log(this.saleData)
    
        })
      }
```

And this is the result:

[image]